# Not to reload the fragment once loaded-ANDROID

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `Android` app I have 6 fragments which are replaced one by one on clicking item in navigation drawer. My problem is that fragment are loaded again and again when clicking on navigation drawer items. I don not want my fragment to reload again and again. Instead I want them to remain in their previous state when switching from fragment to fragment. `Addbacktostack()` is not working.please tell me some other way to do it:

My code is:

```
 @Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    row_view = view;
    displayView(position);

}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragmenta();
            title = "aaaa";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragmentb();
            title = "Introduction";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Glossary();
            title = "Glossary";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            title = "Settings";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FeedbackFragment();
            title = "Feedback";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Fragmentc();
            title = "cc";
            toolbar_title.setText(title);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }



if (myfragmentstate != null) {             // This is always null
        //Restore the fragment's instance
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(myfragmentstate, "mContent");
        Log.i("sadfas","fragment"+fragment);

    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body,fragment);   //always reloads a fragment and i donot want this
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        toolbar_title.setText(title);

    }
}



@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i("MicroRAE","instanmce save"+fragment);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very good solution :

```
String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        toolbar_title.setText(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy: Just declare a global String that saves your last fragment loaded. In the method where you load your fragment, just compare if it´s the same. If not, load the new fragment, if matches, just do nothing.

```
     String lastFragmentLoaded = null; // THIS VARIABLE IS GLOBAL

        //YOUR METHOD THAT LOAD FRAGMENTS
        LoadMyFragment() 
   {
             String currentFragmentName = yourFragment.getClass().getName();

             if(lastFragmentLoaded != currentFragmentName) {
                   //LOAD YOUR FRAGMENTS

             //FINALLY, SAVE YOUR LAST FRAGMENT LOADED TO COMPARE NEXT TIME
             lastFragmentLoaded = currentFragmentName;
        }
        else 
        {
            // LET IT EMPTY IF YOU WANT
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution I found is below:

onSavedInstanceState(): always called inside fragment when activity is going to shut down(Move activity from one to another or config changes). So if we are calling multiple fragments on same activity then We have to use the following approach:

Use OnDestroyView() of the fragment and save the whole object inside that method. Then OnActivityCreated(): Check that if object is null or not(Because this method calls every time). Now restore state of an object here.

Its works always!

To correctly save the instance state of Fragment you should do the following:

1. In the fragment, save instance state by overriding onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onActivityCreated():

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       //Restore the fragment's state here
   }
   }

   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

   //Save the fragment's state here
   ```

   }
2. And important point, in the activity, you have to save the fragment's instance in onSaveInstanceState() and restore in onCreate().

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       //Restore the fragment's instance
       mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");

   }

   }      
   @Override
       protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

   //Save the fragment's instance
   getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: SHALL I HAVE TO SAVE STATE IN BOTH FRAGMENT AND ACTIVITY??

Comment: SaveInstanceState is always resulting null in activity ??

Comment: please edit your question to show the changes you have done @shivanigupta

Comment: please suggest what i have to do next